# Water leaking to basement

Tags: water, leaking

[image]Hello,

It just came to my attention that water has been leaking to the basement in a specific spot anytime there's heavy rain. I was looking at a product called Non-Fibered Black Foundation Coating. It seems to be like a liquid rubber to fill cracks and such. What are my options? Should I do that or just pour concrete on top of it?

Comment: That product will work fine, when you dig down to expose the **outside** of the foundation wall, clean it, and apply the product there. On the inside, you'll probably have water-filled blisters followed by a renewed leak shortly thereafter.

Comment: Can it just be applied around the edges of the outside foundation? In other words, I don't want to dig in the ground and apply. Thoughts?

Comment: Water coming though concrete, usually means a crack.  Cracks must be found and clean, then water proof from the the outside, for a permanent repair.  No one wants to hear this, even me.

Comment: @Thisthingisvalid01 that's fine, if you'd like to waste the product and not fix the leak. So, fine, but also pointless. Crip659 is right.

Comment: We cannot tell exactly where the water is coming in, from the picture.  Maybe you only need to make sure there is a slope away from the building or need to remove what sealing is around the white square/hose and redo with good stuff and no digging.  But should check the foundation walls for cracks, this should be able to be done from inside, unless water is proofed to come from the top only.

Comment: What's behind the door?